# Telling Linux not to keep a file in the cache when it is written to disk

Tags: linux, caching

I am writing a large file to disk from a user-mode application. In parallel to it, I am writing one or more smaller files. The large file won't be read back anytime soon, but the small files could be. I have enough RAM for the application + smaller files, but not enough for the large file. Can I tell the OS not to keep parts of the large file in cache after they are written to disk so that more cache is available for smaller files? I still want writes to the large file be fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I tell the OS not to keep parts of the large file in cache ?

Yes, you probably want to use some system call like [posix_fadvise(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) or [madvise(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html). In weird cases, you might use [readahead(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html)  or [userfaultfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/userfaultfd.2.html) or Linux-specific flags to [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Or very cleverly handle `SIGSEGV` (see [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [eventfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) and [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)) You'll need to write your C program doing that.

But I am not sure that it is worth your development efforts. In many cases, the behavior of a recent [Linux](https://kernel.org/) kernel is *good enough*.

See also [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [linuxatemyram.com](https://linuxatemyram.com/)

You many want to read the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/). It is relevant to your concerns

Conbsider studying for inspiration the source code of *existing* [open-source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) software such as [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/), [GNU Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), etc...

#### Most of the time, it is simply not worth the effort to *explicitly* code something to manage your [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

I guess that [mount(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) options in your `/etc/fstab` file (see [fstab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html)...) are in practice more important. Or changing or tuning your file system (e.g. [ext4(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html), [xfs(5)](http://5)..). Or [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)-ing in large pieces (1Mbytes).

#### Play with [dd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) to measure. See also [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Most applications are not disk-bound, and for those who are disk bound, renting more disk space is cheaper that adding and debugging extra code.

### don't forget to benchmark, e.g. using [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [time(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html)

PS. Don't forget your developer costs. They often are a lot above the price of a RAM module (or of some faster SSD disk).